# SQLite FTS search if there's a word that contains string

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, cpu-word

I want to select all rows that contains an string (for example *abc*)

example:

> abc

> abcd

> 0abc

> 0abcd

I want all the above to be returned.

My first approach was:

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE notes MATCH '^abc*'
```

but it returns 0 results.

Second was:

```
SELECT * FROM notes WHERE notes MATCH '*abc*'
```

but it returns an error (I belive that asterix can't be used as the first character).

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your usage of `^`: your string does not start with `abc`, so it's not a match. According to [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html):

**MATCH '^one'              -- first token in any column must be "one"**

Comment: So then how am I supposed to do?

Comment: Did you try `SELECT * FROM notes WHERE notes LIKE  '%abc%'` @IJustWantToLearn

Comment: i need to do a full text search with lot of data and need very high speed, so MATCH is the single solution